# Initializing non-copyable members

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I need to use a codebase which includes some non-copyable classes. They have declared their assignment operator and copy constructor as private. How can I initialize members of these types in my classes? For example:

```
class non_copyable; // defined somewhere. 
                    // constructor receives a parameter of type `normal_class'
// my_class.hpp
class my_class {
public:
    my_class();
    virtual ~my_class();
private:
    normal_class good_one;
    non_copyable trouble;
};
my_class::my_class() :
        good_one(normal_class(0,0)), 
        trouble(non_copyable(good_one)) { // ====> error
}
```

Currently I'm using pointer to `non_copyable` in `my_class`.

Comment: the best way is to define a new class in which the copy constructor throws a custom Exception "NonCopiableError"
And let your non-copiable class inherit from it

Comment: juanchopanza has the solution for you. But I don't understand `non_copyable` constructor takes `normal_class` object (You can pass `good_one` as shown by juanchopanza), then why were you initialising `trouble` by calling `non_copyable` constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling the copy constructor here, since you are constructing `trouble` from a temporary `non_copyable` instance:

```
trouble(non_copyable(good_one))
//        ^^^ temporary non_copyable.
```

Try this:

```
trouble(good_one)
```

Comment: Didn't read the section in standard. I always use copy constructor in initializer... Thanks for answer. It works fine :)

Comment: @soroush It is not a good idea to use the copy constructor like that. semantically, you are generating unnexessary copies (although they are likely to get elided).

Answer (score 2):

You make the trouble for yourself

```
my_class::my_class() :
        good_one(normal_class(0,0)), 
        trouble(non_copyable(good_one))
```

should be just

```
my_class::my_class() :
        good_one(0,0), 
        trouble(good_one)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming trouble class needs `good_one` to construct; i.e has a constructor that takes a `normal_class` as parameter; you can try this:

```
my_class::my_class() :
        good_one(normal_class(0,0)), 
        trouble(good_one) { 
}
```

But in any situation you are relying on initializer list being called in the right order (because trouble depends on `good_one` being initalized). That might not be the case on a different compiler or even with different compiler options.

I'd suggest not using this pattern, initialize the `good_one` in the initalizer list and then do something like `trouble.SetObject(good_one)` in the constructor.

Or maybe convert trouble to

```
non_copyable* trouble;
[...]
my_class::my_class() :
    good_one(normal_class(0,0))
{ 
    trouble = new non_copyable(good_one); 
}
```